# Do I need a lock in AddOrUpdate of a concurrent dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, locking, concurrentdictionary

in my class I have

```
public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, HashSet<string>> ConnectedUserConnections = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
```

When adding or updating, should I update via:

```
ConnectedUserConnections.AddOrUpdate(userId, new HashSet<string>(), (key, existingVal) =>
                {
                    existingVal.Add(connectionId);
                    return existingVal;
                });
```

or

```
ConnectedUserConnections.AddOrUpdate(userId, new HashSet<string>(), (key, existingVal) =>
                {
                   lock(ConnectedUserConnections)

                    {
                        existingVal.Add(connectionId);
                        return existingVal;
                    }
                });
```

Many thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at the [`public TValue AddOrUpdate(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> addValueFactory, Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> updateValueFactory)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,e5f450835d8600ed) from the reference source,

```
 while (true)
 {
     TValue oldValue;
     if (TryGetValue(key, out oldValue))
     //key exists, try to update
     {
         newValue = updateValueFactory(key, oldValue);
         if (TryUpdate(key, newValue, oldValue))
```

There is no lock until the `TryGetValue`, so if there is already a value for `key`, multiple threads could arrive at the `TryGetValue`, execute it, return `true`, execute the `updateValueFactory` (your method) at the same time and try adding `existingVal.Add(connectionId);`...

So yes, you do need a `lock`.